# How do you put a string starting from a specific position?

Tags: c#, console, cursor-position

I've been trying to figure out a shortcut in putting a long string text positioned in a specific coordinate without using `Console.SetCursorPosition` and `Console.WriteLine` multiple times. I plan on using the shortcut especially in positioning ASCII text.

I've tried doing `Console.SetCursorPosition` then the `@` to put the long string text altogether only to discover that only the first line is affected by the `Console.SetCursorPosition`.

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(50, 1);
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
Console.SetCursorPosition(50, 2);
Console.WriteLine("World");
Console.ReadKey();
```

I expect the output to display `Hello` somehow at the middle with `World` just below it.

Comment: You said _I expect the output to display Hello somehow at the middle with World just below it_, but that is exactly what your code is doing, right?

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to find a shortcut for the code so that it does the same thing as the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function to do this. For example:

```
static void Print(int left, int top, params string[] lines)
{
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        top++;
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Print(50, 1, "Hello", "World");
```

Or equivalently like this:

```
string[] lines = { "Hello", "World" };
Print(50, 1, lines);
```

If the text consists of words separated by spaces, and you want to put a single word on each line, then you can split the text at spaces, inside the function. That way you would be able to pass a single line of text.

```
static void Print(int left, int top, params string[] lines)
{
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string[] words = line.Trim().Split(new char[] { ' ' });
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
            Console.WriteLine(word);
            top++;
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Print(50, 1, "Hello World");
```

Comment: In case of placing a really long text, is there any shortcut instead of doing "text1", "text2", and so on? Nevertheless, it works though, thanks!

Comment: @Rosesinfours - Not sure what you mean by _really long text_. If the text consists of words separated by spaces, and you want to put a single word on each line, then you can split the text at spaces, inside the function. That way you would be able to pass a single line of text.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you wrap it in a function:

```
public static void WriteAtPosition(int x, int y, stfing text)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(x,y);
    Console.Write(text);
}
```